# Replacing empty values with method call ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a map function I am calling on names of values and then sorting them and rejecting blanks. However instead of rejecting blanks I would like to replace the blanks with a different method call. For example right now I am doing:

```
Client.data.map(&:string).sort_by(&:to_s).reject(&:blank?)
```

I want to do it in such a way that I can call Client.data.id_num on those values that are blank (because they do not have string values).

Is there a good way to do this in Ruby? Thanks! I am using Rails, if that helps.

Comment: What about this? `Client.data.map(&:string).sort_by(&:to_s).reject(&:blank?).map { |element| element.presence || Client.data.id_num(element) }`

Comment: I get an undefined method `m‌​ap' for array error from that code.

Comment: Uh? That sounds wrong, because there indeed is a Array#map method. :)

Comment: Here is the full error message: undefined method `m‌​ap' for #<Array:0x007fb356aa1be0>

Comment: Can you provide a simple reproduction example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
Client.data
      .sort_by { |client| client.string.to_s }
      .map { |client| client.string.presence || client.id_num }
```